# Unable to parse few xml nodes.What's the protection applied?

Tags: java, xml, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I have an xml feed like this

```
<item><title>Left hopes BJP surge will eat into Mamata’s votes </title><link>http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533916/s/39439a29/sc/7/l/0Ltimesofindia0Bindiatimes0N0Cindia0CLeft0Ehopes0EBJP0Esurge0Ewill0Eeat0Einto0EMamatas0Evotes0Chome0Clok0Csabha0Celections0C20A140Cnews0CLeft0Ehopes0EBJP0Esurge0Ewill0Eeat0Einto0EMamatas0Evotes0Carticleshow0C336252890Bcms/story01.htm</link><description>At times sworn enemies can be of help to each other, albeit indirectly. In the current political winds of West Bengal, no one knows it better than the Left.&lt;img width='1' height='1' src='http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533916/s/39439a29/sc/7/mf.gif' border='0'/&gt;&lt;br clear='all'/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/194480044196/u/409/f/533916/c/33039/s/39439a29/sc/7/rc/1/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"&gt;&lt;img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/194480044196/u/409/f/533916/c/33039/s/39439a29/sc/7/rc/1/rc.img" border="0"/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/194480044196/u/409/f/533916/c/33039/s/39439a29/sc/7/rc/2/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"&gt;&lt;img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/194480044196/u/409/f/533916/c/33039/s/39439a29/sc/7/rc/2/rc.img" border="0"/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/194480044196/u/409/f/533916/c/33039/s/39439a29/sc/7/rc/3/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"&gt;&lt;img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/194480044196/u/409/f/533916/c/33039/s/39439a29/sc/7/rc/3/rc.img" border="0"/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/194480044196/u/409/f/533916/c/33039/s/39439a29/sc/7/a2.htm"&gt;&lt;img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/194480044196/u/409/f/533916/c/33039/s/39439a29/sc/7/a2.img" border="0"/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;img width="1" height="1" src="http://pi.feedsportal.com/r/194480044196/u/409/f/533916/c/33039/s/39439a29/sc/7/a2t.img" border="0"/&gt;</description><pubDate>Fri, 11 Apr 2014 19:26:07 GMT</pubDate><guid isPermaLink="false">http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/Left-hopes-BJP-surge-will-eat-into-Mamatas-votes/home/lok/sabha/elections/2014/news/Left-hopes-BJP-surge-will-eat-into-Mamatas-votes/articleshow/33625289.cms</guid></item>
```

I am using [Jaunt API](http://jaunt-api.com/jaunt-tutorial.htm) to scrape the news title and link from this feed.Here is the code

```
            agent.visit("http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533916/index.rss");
            Elements items=agent.doc.findEach("<item>");
            for(Element item:items)
            {
                headline=item.findFirst("<title>").getText();
                link=item.findFirst("<link>").getText();
                System.out.println("headline:"+headline+"\nlink:"+link+"\n");
            }
```

Now I am getting all the headlines but null for link!!!.The same thing happened when I was scraping another newspaper feed.Is there any special thing (encoding) about that link node which is giving null or am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it is possible that `findFirst` doesn't handle `<link>` because `findFirst` is more oriented towards comments.  Would `getFirst` with an appropriate query be viable?

Comment: Even `getFirst()` is returning `null` for the `<link>` node.

Comment: I found a surprising behaviour,which might be the problem. When I used `System.out.println(agent.visit("http://www.thehindu.com/news/?service=rss").innerXML());`,It gives `<link /> www.hindu.com/news/...` instead of `<link> www.hindu.com/news/...</link>`.This behaviour is only for the `<link>` node.Other nodes are properly closed.

Comment: Can you guess any solution or reason why `<link>` node is not closed?Though when I see source code for the feed in browser, all the nodes are properly closed,including `<link>` tag also.